# Trouble displaying external webpage within IFrame (Xampp)

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost

I'm creating a webpage using XAMPP as a local server. However when I use the code below and view my webpage, within the iframe I get "*server DNS address could not be found.*" instead of the external webpage (Google).

`echo "<td><iframe src=https://www.google.com</iframe></td>";`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its invalid html

Comment: Do you need quotes around the address? `src='https:/www.google.com'`